# Implement drop(n) and take(n) in Swift

Tags: swift

I've implemented drop and take for arrays in swift.  Desired behavior

```
let list = [1,2,3,4]
list.drop(1)            // [2,3,4]
list.take(2)            // [1,2]
list.drop[1].take[2]    // [2,3]
```

Ran into an issue where a subscripted array is a 'Slice' So seems I have to extend both Array and Slice:

```
extension Slice {
    func take(num: Int) -> Slice<T> {
        let n = (num < self.count) ? num : self.count
        return self[0..n]
    }

    func drop(num: Int) -> Slice<T> {
        let n = (num < self.count) ? num : self.count
        return self[n..self.count]
    }
}

// Extend array to use the Slice extension
extension Array {
    func take(num: Int) -> Slice<T> {
        let slice = Slice(self)
        return slice.take(num)
    }
    func drop(num: Int) -> Slice<T> {
        let slice = Slice(self)
        return slice.drop(num)
    }
}
```

This works.
=>  Is there a better way to do this with Swift's type system?

Comment: I discovered after researching my answer (and trying to implement `dropWhile` and `takeWhile`) that Swift already has `prefix` and `suffix` global functions that do this stuff. If you look at their signatures, they are slightly more general even than mine.

Answer (score 3):

You'll notice that many functions in Swift one would expect to be methods are actually global functions, such as `contains`, `first`, and so on. If you want to implement `take` and `drop` in a truly generic fashion, you must follow this technique. The trick is to create functions that operate on `Sliceable` values. Unfortunately, you cannot write an extension on `Sliceable`, because it uses `Self` and has associated types.

So, what you want to achieve should look something like the following:

```
func take<T: Sliceable where T.Index == Int>(sliceable: T, end: Int) -> T.SubSlice {
    return sliceable[0..<end]
}

func drop<T: Sliceable where T.Index == Int>(sliceable: T, start: Int) -> T.SubSlice {
    return sliceable[start..<countElements(sliceable)]
}
```

I spent all of two minutes on these, although I did some rudimentary testing and they work just fine.

While I believe this is the most "general" solution you can get in Swift, it's sub-optimal in my opinion. The advantage it has over yours is that it works on *any* `Sliceable` type, such as `String`. The disadvantage is that the syntax sucks. You can't use a fluent style with it:

```
take(drop(array, 3), 7)
```

versus the much more fluent

```
array.drop(3).take(7)
```

I think Swift's type system has a little way to go before it is optimal, but it's an improvement over Objective-C.

## Update

Since I wrote this, I became aware of Swift's `prefix` and `suffix` global functions. These should be used instead.

Comment: Should be the accepted answer - `prefix` and `suffix` are the way to go

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation looks absolutely fine to me! A range-based away subscript is a `Slice` type for performance reasons. It does not copy the indicated sub-array, instead it just points to the range defined by the `Range` you provide to the subscript.